# Python - How to loop through an output of a sql server query and save each row of the output as a rtf file

Tags: python, sql-server

I am new to Python and try to learn Python through solving the problems I encountered in my daily work.

Here is the problem.

I developed four stored procedures (SQL Server), the 1st one will return a list of report IDs, the 2nd one will return the code of the report body when you pass a report ID to it, the 3rd one will return the report name when you pass a report ID to it and the 4th one will update a flag to remove the processed report ID from the report ID list.

Now I would like to develop a Python script that will call the 1st stored procedures(SP) to get the report ID list, then loop through the IDs to call the 2nd stored procedure to get the code of each report body and save as a .rtf file. In the end, rename the .rtf file based on the report name out of the 3rd SP and update the flag using the 4th SP.

Thanks.

So far, I am able to connect to the database server using pyodbc and get the list of all the report IDs:

```py
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=test;'
                      'Database=test;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[GetIDList]')

for row in cursor:
```

I am stuck at the step to fetch the first ID of the list and pass it to another store procedure to get the report body.

Comment: Show us the code you've tried, and tell us specifically where you're having difficulty

Comment: @allmhuran thanks for your quick reply, I updated what I have so far.

Comment: you can iterate over small amounts of data using `for row in cursor.fetchall()`, and you can access the columns in the returned dataset by name or index. For example, to do it by index you would use `row[0]`, `row[1]`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Granted test is value and not variables;

change

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=test;'
                      'Database=test;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

to

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};' +
                      'Server=test;' +
                      'Database=test;' +
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

Comment: Python will concatenate adjacent string literals even without the `+`. The parentheses help with that.